# How do you add a console.log method on to arrays and objects prototypes in JavaScript using the dot notation?

Tags: javascript, logging

How can you create a log method on arrays and objects in javascript using the dot notation?

```js
function log(...k){

console.log.apply(console, k)

}

log('hello') //=> prints hello


//I want to do this for arrays and objects using the dot notation


['hello','world'].log() //=> prints ['hello', 'world']


{'hello':'world'}.log() //=> prints {'hello', 'world'}
```

Comment: Array.prototype.log =

Comment: if that worked I wouldn't be asking...

Comment: @Arrow check my below answer to see if it fixes your problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could add this method to the prototype of arrays, like below:

```js
var array = ['hello','world'];
Array.prototype.log = function(){
    (this).forEach(function(item){
        console.log(item);
    });
};
array.log();
```

Regarding an object you could do the same by adding you function to the object prototype:

```js
var obj = { 'hello' : 'world' };
Object.prototype.log = function(){
  Object.keys(this).forEach(function(key){
      console.log(key);
      console.log((obj[key]));
    });
};
obj.log();
```

Comment: Thanks, Christos exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: I'm not going to tell you not to modify native prototypes as some would. Please do it in a more proper way. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just like you said, modify the prototypes.

```js
function log(...k) {
  console.log.apply(console, k);
}

Array.prototype.log = function() {
  log.apply(null, ['['].concat(this).concat([']']));
};

Object.prototype.log = function() {
  let vals = ['{'];
  for (var key in this) {
    if (this.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      vals.push(key, this[key]);
    }
  }
  vals.push('}');
  log.apply(null, vals);
};

['hello', 'world'].log();
({ hello: 'world' }).log();
```

Comment: You answer the question, However, your answer seems more involved. Can you shorten it?

Comment: @Arrow It's not really more involved at all. I'm just calling your `log` function.

Comment: Same warning here. Just cramming stuff on to native prototype objects is really bad form. It can cause lots of problems as your new methods are enumerable and that can mess things up.

Comment: @gforce301 True, attaching things to the prototype is generally a bad idea. But it is was the OP requested.

Comment: See my answer below. There is a better way.

Comment: @gforce301 Yours is a *safer* way. The only difference is it won't overwrite a previous implementation (which may or may not be the desired behavior) and prevents it from being enumerated.

Comment: You can remove the `if` block if you want to overwrite. I can't see where jamming methods as enumerable properties is ever wanted behavior on a native prototype. Nothing like breaking tons of libraries and existing code for want of a simple log function. But hey it's just my opinion

Comment: @gforce301 It all depends on what your goal is. If the existing implementation is broken, you may want to replace it. If you aren't relying on terrible libraries which modify the native prototypes then it isn't a problem. As it is, it's almost always a bad idea to modify the native prototypes unless you're putting in a polyfill.

Answer (score 0):

Please don't just munge native prototypes indiscriminately. This can (and most likely will) cause you massive headaches. Instead use [Object.defineProperty()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) and define your new methods properly.

```js
Array.prototype.log = Array.prototype.log;
if(Array.prototype.log === undefined) {
    Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'log', {
        enumerable: false,
        value: function () {
            (this).forEach(function(item){
                console.log(item);
            });
        }
    });
}

Object.prototype.log = Object.prototype.log;
if(Object.prototype.log === undefined) {
    Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, 'log', {
        enumerable: false,
        value: function (el, offset) {
        var self = this;
            Object.keys(this).forEach(function(key){
              console.log(key + ':', (self[key]));
            });
        }
    });
}

var testArr = [1, 2, 'foo', 'bar'];
var testObj = {one: 1, two: 2, foo: 'bar'};

testArr.log();
testObj.log();
```

Comment: Why are you assigning the values to themselves? `Object.prototype.log = Object.prototype.log;` may as well be a noop.

Answer (score 0):

In javascript there is what is been called `prototypes`. `Prototypes` are also `objects`, that you can assign members (`methods` `properties`)to. In your case , if you want to create a function that works for a particular primitive value, you have to add that particular function as a method to the prototype of the constructor function of the primitive value. For example in your case, you have to create a function as a method on the prototype of the `Array` and `Object` constructor functions

**example**

```
Array.prototype.log = function() {    
    for ( let __elements of this ) {
        // uh
        // incase it's an array of array
        if ( Array.isArray(__elements) ) {
            __elements.log();
        } else {
            console.log(__elements);
        }
    } 
};



Object.prototype.log = function() {
    for ( let _prop in this ) {
        // typeof [] always returns an object
        if ( this.hasOwnProperty(_prop) ) {
            if ( typeof this[_prop] === 'object' && ! 
                Array.isArray(this[_prop]) ) {
                this[_prop].log();
            } else {
                console.log(this[_prop]);
            }
        }
    }
};


[1,2,3,4].log();

[[1,2,[3,4]],3,[2]].log();

let obj = {
    name:"victory",
    surname: "osikwemhe",
    life: {
        occupation: ["accontant","programmer"],
        hobbies: "danching gnamgnam style",
        hates: "sharing my wifi",
        tvshows: {
            "cw": ["the flash"],
            "hbo": ["silicon valley"],
            "history": ["vikings"]
        }        
    } 
};


obj.log();
```

in case you are worthering what the `this` point to, `this` points to the primitive value we use the log method on

Comment: Your answer for array does not return its original structure, just the values in it.

Comment: @Arrow if you want the original structure, just remove the if conditional statement and a console.log(__elements)